# Pandas swap value if the value is found in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns with a list of each strings, named Tag 1, Tag 2. In simple terms I need to check if a string in a cell is found anywhere in the adjacent column and if so, swap the values.

**Existing Dataframe**

```
Tag 1    Tag 2
Amazon   Twitter
Amazon   Google
eBay     Amazon
Reddit   Facebook
```

**Desired Output**

```
Tag 1    Tag 2
Amazon   Twitter
Amazon   Google
Amazon   eBay
Reddit   Facebook
```

In the desired outcome, you can see that Amazon has switched places with eBay because it was found in the Tag 1 column.

**Minimum Reproducible Example**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Tag 1': ['Amazon', 'Amazon', 'eBay', 'Reddit'],
        'Tag 2': ['Twitter', 'Google', 'Amazon', 'Facebook']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I've been researching similar posts but can't quite seem to get it exactly right.

Here's my code so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`pd.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) to check when a value in 'Tag 2' existis in 'Tag 1' using `isin` and swap the values when you assign back:

```
df[['Tag 1','Tag 2']] = df[['Tag 2','Tag 1']].where(
    df['Tag 2'].isin(df['Tag 1'].tolist()), df[['Tag 1','Tag 2']].values)
```

prints back:

```
    Tag 1     Tag 2
0  Amazon   Twitter
1  Amazon    Google
2  Amazon      eBay
3  Reddit  Facebook
```

Comment: Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)  the answers if it has solved your issue :)

Comment: I might have jumped the gun a little, finding values which haven't been swapped in a large df. Your code is super efficient, just not quite working and I'm not sure why!

Comment: Are the values always written in exactly the same way? Or would have differences and typo's?

Comment: I'm an idiot, I've figured it out! Your code works fine and is the fastest. It's because sometimes the second value matches and it swaps back in. In my example, eBay would be swapped back in if it's found too. Doh! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This might do it

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Tag 1': ['Amazon', 'Amazon', 'eBay', 'Reddit'],
        'Tag 2': ['Twitter', 'Google', 'Amazon', 'Facebook']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

values = np.unique(df['Tag 1'].values)  # All unique values in Tag 1
swapped = []  # So we don't double swap

for val in values:
    rows = df.loc[df['Tag 2'] == val]  # Get rows in Tag 2 that matches
    for idx, row in rows.iterrows():
        if idx in swapped:  # Ignore if already swapped
            continue
        # Swap the values
        temp = df.iloc[idx]['Tag 2']
        df.iloc[idx]['Tag 2'] = df.iloc[idx]['Tag 1']
        df.iloc[idx]['Tag 1'] = temp
        swapped.append(idx)
```

There are probably more efficient solutions, but I think this is pretty clear. It goes through each unique value in the 'Tag 1' column and checks for matches in the 'Tag 2' column, and swaps them. I was not sure if you wanted to avoid double swaps, but that can be removed if it's not a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @sophocles is probably the right.

However if you just want to reorder columns in a lexicographical order for instance, try:

```
tags = ['Tag 1', 'Tag 2']

df[tags] = df[tags].apply(lambda x: sorted(tuple(x)), axis=1, result_type='expand')
print(df)

# Output
      Tag 1    Tag 2
0    Amazon  Twitter
1    Amazon   Google
2    Amazon     eBay
3  Facebook   Reddit
```

Comment: Hi @Corralien, IIUC this will always bring to Tag 1 the value based on the first character of the word right? It's like sorting, on each row and then expanding the tuple into two separate columns?

Comment: @sophocles. You're totally right. It's just an alternative. I said your answer was the right.